# Await Tasks versus Checking Task.Status in while

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

**problem description:** I got console application with 3 Tasks which make some calculation on the server(local). When I used await Task.WhenAll() or alternative Task.WaitAll(), time of computation these Tasks takes similar time as if I run these Tasks in synchronous approach. I was hopeless so I tried use the while loop to check the Task status. So my code now looks like>

```
    public  void DoTask(PIServer server, AFTimeRange timeRange)
     {
        var timeRanges = DivideTheTimeRange(timeRange);
        Task[] tasksArray = new Task[3];
        watch.Start();
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        tasksArray[0] = (Task.Run(() => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, timeRanges[0])));
        tasksArray[1] = (Task.Run(() => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, timeRanges[1])));
        tasksArray[2] = (Task.Run(() => CalculationClass.AverageValueOfTagPerDay(server, timeRanges[2])));
        while (tasksArray[tasksArray.Count() - 1].Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        { }
        //while (!Task.WaitAll(tasksArray,-1))
        //{}

        Task.WaitAll(tasksArray);
        //await Task.WhenAll(tasksArray); in case the method got async keyword
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Final elapsed time is" + watch.Elapsed);
      }

 public static void AverageValueOfTagPerDay(PIServer server, AFTimeRange timeRange)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread in AVERAGE()> {0} task> {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,Task.CurrentId);

        var listOfAverage = new Dictionary<PIPoint, AFValues>();
        PIPagingConfiguration config = new PIPagingConfiguration(PIPageType.TagCount, 1);
        PIPointList pointList = new PIPointList();
        pointList.Add(PIPoint.FindPIPoint(server, "HugeTestingTag_ADracka"));
        AFTimeSpan timeSpan = new AFTimeSpan(days: 1);
            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            var listResults = pointList.Summaries(timeRange, timeSpan, OSIsoft.AF.Data.AFSummaryTypes.Average, OSIsoft.AF.Data.AFCalculationBasis.TimeWeighted,
                OSIsoft.AF.Data.AFTimestampCalculation.Auto, config);
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time >{0} for task>{1}", s.Elapsed,Task.CurrentId);
            foreach (var item in listResults)
            {   
                AFValues values = item[OSIsoft.AF.Data.AFSummaryTypes.Average];
                PIPoint point = values.PIPoint;
                listOfAverage[point] = values;
            }
        Program.Show(listOfAverage);
    }
```

I measure calculation time in AverageValueOfTagPerDay() method.With this code I can achieve my goal (calculations are 50% faster in average) but **I dont know why.**  Also I tried use in while loop Task.WaitAll() method but this doesnt help either.
So why checking Task.Status in while loop makes my Tasks faster then method Task.WhenAll ??? I dont get it.

> Result **without** WHILE loop:[image: While loop is commented]
>   Result **with** WHILE loop:[image]

**UPDATE 2**

> Result with Thread.Sleep(1000) in AverageValueOfTagPerDay: [image]
>   In case that i comment that WHILE loop elapsed time is a bit faster: 1.04

Comment: Doesn't that only wait on one task? Like `WaitAny`

Comment: The code you show us only checks the completion of the last tak in the while loop. And I don't see how you could possibly monitor anything with this code. Provide us with the code you used to measure performance, and also with a sample of your result and maybe we can answer you. Right now it would be nothing more than wild guesses.

Comment: No, notice that Task.WaitAll() method. Ok I will do that Thanks Falanwe

Comment: Ok I updated it. Hope it will help

Comment: Post executable code. Replace the body of AverageValueOfTagPerDay with Thread.Sleep(1000).

Comment: If I get it you wanna see image with alter AverageValueOfTagPerDay(). Is that correct? (Update2)

Comment: Yes, that was the test I wanted to perform. As you can see the waiting logic does not matter at all. The contents of your work function do. Too much unknown stuff there to diagnose.

Comment: I see, so this behavior is related with the calculation on server I guess. Well it works so I just would like know why. Still thank for your advices

Answer (score 0):

```
while (tasksArray[tasksArray.Count() - 1].Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{ }
```

It only checks the last task, you have to loop on the whole array. The last task might be faster because it's probably working on the smallest range.

Try with the following :

```
while (tasksArray.Any(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
{ }
```

Comment: You obviously dont get it. I explain this in the comments.I dont need check all Tasks because this last Task will finish like the last one(in the most of cases). And after that I still got Task.WaitAll() method so it is pointless and also it doesnt explain why it is faster.